# Non-invocable member "DevExpress.Xtragrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.Columns" cannot be used like a method?

Tags: winforms, gridview, devexpress, textedit

I want to get TextEdit value to cell in GridView soI tried this code

`gridView1.SetRowCellValue(GridControl.NewItemRowHandle, gridView1.Columns("forignkey"), textEdit12.Text);`

Am getting error on Column is ""Non-invocable member cannot be used like a method"" How to solve the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Columns is a collection (list), not a function. The indexer for collections/lists should be written with square brackets, not round brackets.

```
gridView1.Columns["forignkey"]
```

so the whole source should look like

```
gridView1.SetRowCellValue(GridControl.NewItemRowHandle, gridView1.Columns["forignkey"], textEdit12.Text);
```

Comment: Hi, now error wont come but i didn't get any values when i load the form ? "GridControl.NewItemRowHandle" i think error comes in the area ? can u tell how to resolve this ?

Comment: Check spelling? forignkey should be written "foreignkey" if anything.
NewItemRowHandle should work fine as it is.

Comment: spelling is correct only. but still error ?? can u tel when this "NewItemRowHandle" event fired ? I write this code on Form_Load